# How to install Tuxpaint on Debian 7?

Tags: debian, software-installation

I want to use tuxpaint in Debian 7. Is there any software to get this software? I can't change my operating system.

When I try to install through `apt-get`, I get this:

```
utkarsh@Utkarsh[~]$sudo apt-get install tuxpaint
[sudo] password for utkarsh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tuxpaint
utkarsh@Utkarsh[~]$
```

#### EDIT #1

```
root@Utkarsh[utkarsh]#lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-3.0-ia32:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-ia32:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-ia32:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-ia32:cxx-4.0-noarch:cxx-4.1-ia32:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-3.1-ia32:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-ia32:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-ia32:desktop-4.0-noarch:desktop-4.1-ia32:desktop-4.1-noarch:graphics-2.0-ia32:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-ia32:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-ia32:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.1-ia32:graphics-4.1-noarch:languages-3.2-ia32:languages-3.2-noarch:languages-4.0-ia32:languages-4.0-noarch:languages-4.1-ia32:languages-4.1-noarch:multimedia-3.2-ia32:multimedia-3.2-noarch:multimedia-4.0-ia32:multimedia-4.0-noarch:multimedia-4.1-ia32:multimedia-4.1-noarch:printing-3.2-ia32:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch:printing-4.1-ia32:printing-4.1-noarch:qt4-3.1-ia32:qt4-3.1-noarch:security-4.0-ia32:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-ia32:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: BOSS
Description:    BOSS GNU/Linux 5.0 (anokha)
Release:    5.0
Codename:   anokha
```

Comment: Please edit your question add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to it.

Comment: Can you please ad the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: @htor 

`bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied`

Comment: @slm 

http://freetexthost.com/24ql3fjcvp

Answer (score 0):

It's for debian too.

```
sudo apt-get install tuxpaint
```

As that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install update` before installing Tuxpaint.

Package link/alternative way to install (without terminal) [here](http://tuxpaint.org/download/linux-debian/).

Comment: Please don't use caps and put the log like you did before you edited. Anyway, try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install tuxpaint` after, that should really work as it's there for Debian 7.

Answer (score 0):

Debian is the base Linux distribution that Ubuntu derives/derived from so both distributions make use of the same type of packages. The packages are bundled into a file format called .deb. Yes the name `.deb` is because it originated with, you guessed it, Debian.

You can search for the package using `apt` from the command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-cache search tuxpaint
```

If you find it you can install it using this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tuxpaint
```

If you cannot find a package through `apt` you can resort to searching on Debian package search website:

- http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=tuxpaint

Doing so I found several references to tuxpaint. Looking through this page you have Debian 7 (code name's Wheezy) which is on this page so something else is going on.